# How to submit a form when validation fails

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to submit a `form` which contains some fields that may be `invalid`. For example, there may be some fields that have attribute `allowBlank` set to `false`. I tried to do this before submitting:

```
myform.getForm().getFields().each(function(field){
   if(field.allowBlank==false) field.allowBlank=true; // <- has no effect
});

myform.getForm().submit({ .... // <- still not submitted
```

But it has no effect, the form is not submitted, even though `myform.getForm().isValid()` returns `true`.

**EDIT**

To prevent voting down I want to clarify. I know, that this is normal behaviour, but I need a workaround for some special functionality. I submit the form not to insert values into the database, but to check current values in the form's fields. And in some case, depending on the values, I want to hide some fields. This is necessary when I have a `parent object` with some `child objects` that share their parent's fields. But these child objects may differ from one another. So, when a field `object type` has a value `child one`, I want to hide certain fields that pertain to `child two`. But to check this, I need to submit the form, and this is where the problem comes out.

Comment: Did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: No. I have done it yet. If you have an idea, please, post it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of Vtypes in Ext which I think will solve your problem.

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    firstName: function(val, field) {
        // Use a condition if you need to, otherwise just return true value
        if (val == '123') {
            return true;   
        }

        return false;
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Sample Form'
    ,width: 300
    ,bodyPadding: 10
    ,renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield'
        ,name: 'first name'
        ,fieldLabel: 'First Name'
        ,vtype: 'firstName' // <-- vtype here
        ,allowBlank: false
    }]
});
```

Even if you have `allowBlank: false` and you decided to return `true` value in your `vtype` method, you will still have a valid field that will allow you to submit your form.